# Table of flat callers

Tags: texas-hold-em

OK I have been playing poker for 15+ years now and of course the game has changed over the years.  I play in a few leagues and in a particular league I play with a bunch of flat callers they don't raise often at all.  Now I tried to be aggressive agianst them by raising but they all call the raise.  So 4 flat callers for $200 im in BB I raise $1000 all 4 call.  2 have big hands like KK and JJ or AA they never raise they just always flat call.  I try just calling and playing my hand and the board ut they will catch against my hands when they just flat call with junk A rag and such and they will call a big raise with A Rag.  What would be the best way to play these guys?  They are not really that good so its hard to play situational with them because they don't understand the game that well.  I usually play with good poker players and bigger stakes so I do understand the variance is going to be higher but man I just get it wrong every time!

Comment: Where is this game? ;-)

Comment: Agreed! Chris, what are you complaining about? You are cleaning up, right?

Answer (score 4):

These players are called loose passive players, and are very easy to beat with patience, I picked out a passage from an article that I really believe sums up the perfect strategy against these players.

> Stop bluffing the loose-passives, respect any aggression they show, and value bet them out of the water, and you should do just fine.
>   [This is a nice article explaining how to play against callers](https://www.pokernews.com/strategy/how-to-beat-loose-passive-poker-players-21257.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There was a question here about PlayWSOP was rigged so I got an account to see if I saw anything to confirm.  I saw no evidence it was rigged.  But that is how most of the low (play) money games are played.

When the table is loose then play tight.  If you get a lot of post flop callers then you can play some good draws as you can get good payouts.

Position does not matter as much but it still matters.

For sure play AA, KK, AK, QQ can raise to build the pot.  But if you don't hit  and you have 6 in the pot with a wet board then play it slow.  Fold if it gets too expensive.

I will flat call in mid to late with with any pair or suited connects 6 or above.  If you hit then punish and if not get away.  If you have 8+ outs you are probably going to get immediate pots odds to call.  They often don't even recognize when a straight or flush draw completes on the turn or river.

You need to adjust what is a show down hand.  Top pair against a single opponent has show down value.  Against 6 top pair probably needs to improve.  Need more like top or middle set against 6 to be a shown down type hand. Hang around with just top pair but if it gets expensive then get out.

You can typically win against a table like this but the frustration is that it can take a while.

Answer (score 1):

Loose passive players (calling stations) are actually easy to beat. Limp with them with speculative hands such as small pairs / suited connectors and try to flop big. Well against these players you need to play your middle pairs as small pairs as well as you don't want to play a big pot unless you hit a set. And when you get premium hands (QQ+) make a massive raise over the top and as a first in.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, what are you complaining about? You are cleaning up, right?

1. Fold everything but premium starting hands
2. bet those to the max
3. be willing to fold to the occasional scary flop
4. rake in the chips

This is a dream table

Comment: Why the downvote?